# Drawing a box at the bottom of the page

Tags: header-footer

I want to draw a box with some text inside at the bottom of a page, and remove that page number.

So far, I can draw the box and fill it with text using the table environment. I'm using the `p` option to make it have its own page.

But I can't make it appear at the bottom, I tried the 'b' option and the `\null \vfill` commands and nothing seems to be working...

Also, the page number won't disappear, even when I type `\thispagestyle{empty}` D:

This is the document

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, draft]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

To give more details, I have a custom page in a separate file, and the page with the box should follow that one, but if I simply try to add the code of the box after it, it gets mixed with other pages.

I tried the `\newpage` command, but the problem still remained, then I tried to create a separate file for the box code, but it didn't make any difference. The only time I got something was with the `p` option, but with that I have no control of where the box should be placed.

I hope that the following code represents the error properly...

```
\input{./file.tex}

\begin{table}[p]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
        \hline
        Random text\\ in\\ the box
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section*{Section}
A new section I start, that's the part that mixed with the table if I remove the 'p' option.
```

And the file.tex, just for the sake of the example

```
Some formatted text all over the page.

\newpage
%Still worked even without this command.
```

Can someone give me some help, please? :)

Comment: Hope I got it right this time :)

Comment: You definitely made progress, but what is `\input{./file.tex}`? Does that matter for the table at the bottom. Also, you only want it at the bottom of one page?  Still would be better to have something I could simply cut and paste and get started on solving problem..

Comment: The separate file contain some formatted text which I don't believe influence what comes next. And yes, I just want a separate page with a box at the bottom and no numbering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

[image]

The above image is the bottom of Page 3. Pages 2 and 4 have the numbering.

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text. It is not needed in your document.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[ondesided]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
{% Group this so that these changes are kept local
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vfill
\hfill
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|}
        \hline
        Random text\\ 
        in\\ 
        the box\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\hfill%
}

\section*{Section}
A new section I start, that's the part that mixed with the table if I remove the 'p' option.
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```